# keep showing this error "video system not initialized"

Tags: python, pygame

This is a pretty simple code but it keeps showing me this error I tried multiple stuff but didn't work, I am a beginner and i can't figure out what's wrong
as far i know this error occurs when u dont initialize your code with pygame.init but i did, any ides ?

```
import pygame, sys
from SETTINGS import *
from level import Level

class Game:
    def _init_(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height,size))
        pygame.display.set_caption("pydew valley")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.level = Level()

    def run(self):
        while True: 
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            dt = self.Clock.tick()/ 1000
            self.level.run(dt)
            pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
game.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double underscore instead of single one in init.

```
   def __init__(self):
```

Comment: lmaoo bro thanks didn't see it